# issue adding table row to table layout

Tags: java, android, tablelayout, tablerow

I have the following code:

```
HashMap<String, String> tip = venue.tips.get(j);
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            TableRow.LayoutParams tableRowParams =
                  new TableRow.LayoutParams
                  (TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            tr.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);

            LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            ll.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            TextView tips = new TextView(this);
            tips.setText(tip.get("text"));
            Log.v("TIPS TEXT", tip.get("text"));
            tips.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                     LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                     LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            ImageView avatar = new ImageView(this);
            avatar.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(tip.get("photo")));
            Log.v("PHOTO URL", tip.get("photo"));
            avatar.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            ll.addView(tips);
            ll.addView(avatar);

            tr.addView(ll);

            View v = new View(this);
            v.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1));
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(51, 51, 51));

            tipsTable.addView(tr,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                      LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                      LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tipsTable.addView(v);
```

I think I did something wrong with setting up the layout, but the issue now is that I can't see the rows added to the tipsTable. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not calling [setContentView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setContentView%28android.view.View%29) anywhere. You create this layout but never assign it to the activity. I think what you want to do is after you've set up all your layout stuff:

```
setContentView(ll);
```

Answer (score 0):

along the same line: tipsTable seems to be your top view so try setContentView(tipsTable)